# Submitting a site that has a redirect

Tags: redirects, url

I have a blog site which lives in my subdirectory (www.mysite.com/blog) but I've set a redirect to show up in root url as in www.mysite.com.

Now when I submit my site to Google, do I need to add the actual subdirectory url? or would it be able to know with the root url?

Comment: As long as the redirect is okay, you do not have to do anything special. Just have fun!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google will be happy with either link, but it will likely show the resulting link in the search engine results so users don't have to be transferred to a redirect when clicking on a result.

In your case, if you want mysite.com to appear in the results pages instead of mysite.com/blog to appear, then you need to have mysite.com point to content instead of a redirect, but if everything is at mysite.com/blog then it would make sense to redirect mysite.com to mysite.com/blog and have mysite.com/blog appear in search results. I'm sure not too many people pay attention to the URLs in the search results. They pay more attention to what happens when they click on the blue title above the URL.

Comment: I don't think they are looking either. The users just want results. I do not think they give a fig where or how it appears within the site structure.

Comment: Thanks, I was just curious whether Google would want the actual directory. I second that people really only care about the content. For analytics, I registered with the actual directory path to track down the blog specifically.